# How to access a remote web service by Camel CXF endpoint?

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I was looking up online how to create a Camel's CXF producer (i.e. create a CXF endpoint that would produce a request to some local/remote web service). Generally, all the examples I could find would list the following steps:

*First define the `cxfEndpoint` attributes:*

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
id="orderEndpoint"
address="http://localhost:9000/order/"
serviceClass="camelinaction.order.OrderEndpoint"/>
```

*Then send the request to that endpoint:*

```
...to("cxf:bean:orderEndpoint");
```

Hmmm. I don't understand the concept. If this is a remote web service, all I usually have is the URL of the WSDL. I can get from it the address of the service... but I don't know what the serviceClass is and I don't have it on my classpath.

So how do I define that cxfEndpoint in case I only have the URL of the WSDL?

Or is there another type of endpoint I should use in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into WSDL first for cxf.  Below are two links that I think should help you out quite a lot and has helped me in the past as well.

http://code.notsoclever.cc/camel-cxf-component-wsdl-first-example/

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.0/html-single/Web_Services_and_Routing_with_Camel_CXF/index.html#ImplWs-WsdlFirst

On the Red Hat site you will need to start at chapter 3.

Hope this helps.